# How to add product size in Magento 2.3 order confirmation email?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am trying to edit the confirmation email which the client is receiving upon making a new order. So far I've managed to style it up but I am not able to add collumn which can display the product size number which has been picked. Could someone please tell me how can I add this product attribute in the email. I have tried to follow this [Get product attritube in order confirmation email](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266688/get-product-attribute-into-order-confirmation-email) but I am not able to display the size still. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think help some code try In `<Vendor>/Email/Block/Order/Email/Items/DefaultItems.php` I put

```
public  function getProductModel($id)
    {
        $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($id);
        return $product;
    }
```

and in `<Vendor>/Email/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml` I've called the method like so:

```
$_product = $block->getProductModel($_item->getProductId());
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText("lead_time_title");   ?>
```

And more information read this link :-

**[Magento 2: Add Custom Attribute to New Order Transactional Emails](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178618/magento-2-add-custom-attribute-to-new-order-transactional-emails)**

Hope this help you

Thanks ...